# TeX-PDF and VIM configuration

Tags: vim, latex

I somehow cannot get the [TeX-PDF](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3230) plugin to compile the files appropriately. It states in the [plugin description](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3230) that it defaults ot pdflatex, which I have on my Windows 7, it is mapped in the path variable. It spits out the error:

```
compiled with errors
```

which is baically an undefined case (there are no errors in the file, it compiles with pdflatex from the cmd well).

I tried almost all of the solutions for VIM (like vim-latex, atp, etc) but I can't get them to work with pdflatex. I just want to be able to avoid the process in the command line. I need a step by step, or really well explained guide, because I am sick of reading all the manuals from top to bottom, and not having a result.

Answer (score 1):

If you

```
:set shellcmdflag=/k
```

any external shell command invoked from Vim will *keep* the console window open. You'll see the exact command-line that the plugin uses to compile, and can investigate from there what's wrong. Once you've found the problem, you need to "work backwards" to see how you can get the fix into the plugin; maybe there's a setting to influence the compilation. (I don't know / use the plugin myself.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, unfortunately, I don't even get to the stage of command prompt ...